# the method preparestatement(String) is undefined error

Tags: java, eclipse, prepared-statement

Following is my servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import connection.Connection;

@WebServlet("/Check")
public class Check extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

Connection con;
//PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("Insert into account_master(name,acct_opn_date,cif_id,address) values(?,?,?,?)");
PreparedStatement pstmt= con.prepareStatement("Insert into account_master(name,acct_opn_date,cif_id,address) values(?,?,?,?)");
}
```

Here in the last statement, I am getting error in Eclipse

**Multiple markers at this line

- Watchpoint:Check [access and modification] - pstmt
- The method prepareStatement(String) is undefined for the type 
   Connection**

Following is my connection class:

```
package connection;
import java.sql.*;

public class Connection {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    String username="system";
    String password="root";
try{

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    try {
          DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE",username,password);
        //DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:system/root@localhost:1521:XE");
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.err.println("Problem in connection");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
{
    System.err.println("Error loading driver");
}
}

}
```

Comment: There is no method `prepareStatement` in your `Connection` class, isn't this obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the JDBC Connection class with your own connection class.

You can rename your connection class to a ConnectionBuilder class:

```
public class ConnectionBuilder {
    String username="system";
    String password="root";

    public static Connection buildConnection () {
        try{
           Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
           try {
               return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE",username,password);
           } catch (SQLException e) {
               System.err.println("Problem in connection");
               e.printStackTrace();
                return null; // better throw an exception
           }
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error loading driver");
            return null; // better throw an exception
        }
    }
}
```

And your Check class should use this method:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = ConnectionBuilder.buildConnection().prepareStatement(...);
```